# Convert discord username to member object

Tags: python, discord.py, mysql-connector-python

I have the following script,

```
async def kick(ctx, u: discord.User):
    await client.kick(u)
```

It does have `pass_context=True` but that is in the primary function.

This script works but the problem is that it is passing a string with the author id (example: `johnwayne#345`) that has been pulled from a database while the kick command is expecting a member object.

How can I use this to look up a member object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure `u` is just a string? I just checked and for me it's passing a User object.

However, where I think the problem lies is that you're not calling kick correctly. You want to call Guild.kick or Member.kick. I'm assuming `client` is your actual botclient and that does not have a kick command.

EDIT:

So assuming the kick command receives the id of a member as a string every time you call it, you can use the following. You won't actually have to pass `u: discord.User` since it's only passing a string.

```
@client.command()   
async def kick(ctx, id):
    await ctx.guild.kick(ctx.guild.get_member(int(id)))
```

Since you mentioned in your question that you save their id in a database but then gave the example of their name I'll include the following in case you're saving their names and not the actual User.id.

```
@botclient.command()   
async def kick(ctx, name):
    await ctx.guild.kick(ctx.guild.get_member_named(name))
```

Comment: Did you save it to a database then query it? This is to keep track of repeat offenders. When it saves to the database it saves just the member.id as a string and then when I query it I only have the string.

Comment: Ah I missed that part of your question. if you have the ```id``` you can get the member object by using ```Guild.get_member(id)```. I'll update my answer to include that.

Comment: I figured out why lookup doesn't work with the examplename#2342, that is two attributes combined, the name and the discriminator. I rewrote my script that puts everything in the database. I now store the userid and the username. (username just incase I want to peak in the database manually. However, now my kick command isn't working so I am going to try the first one you posted. It looks like it should do the trick! Thanks!